# Случайно удалил .NET Framework

Tags: .net

Я случайно удалил .NET Framework и теперь не могу запустить проект в VS.
При открытии проекта получаю сообщение:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Выбрал второй пункт и перешел на сайт:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Пробовал установить 4.6 и 4.5. Когда устанавливаю 4.5, говорит что уже есть более новая версия, а установка 4.6 ничего не дала.

Вот перечень моих установленных .NET Framework:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Подскажите, что мне нужно установить, чтобы ошибка ушла?

Comment: Вы пробовали первый вариант ответа в диалоговом окне?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Окно с ошибкой закрывается, в Solution Explorer отображается структура проекта, но открыть ничего оттуда не могу. Проект на WinForms. Не открываются ни формы, ни код

Comment: Попробуй принудительно прокачать обновления для Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустите Repair для Visual Studio (через установку и удаление программ)
Должно помочь

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что можно попробовать все Framework деинсталировать из "Удаление и установка программ". 
А потом уже новый ставить Framework, можно сразу 4.6